# How to import jQuery in weboage absent of it

Tags: jquery, debugging, html

I found jQuery is really useful, especially for its convenient selectors.

Because of its ease-of-use, I am more comfortable with this higher level JS library instead of the naive JS.

Think of this case:

I am visiting a webpage that has **no** jQuery imported.

In order to better make sense how the webpage's JS code works, I hope to import jQuery in the webpage so that I can work more efficiently

How can I do that? Tips on how to do it in Chrome and Firefox will be the best.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox has a Firebug Plugin called FireQuery, which can jquerify the current Page with a push of a button.

Otherwise save this as a bookmark:

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';})();
```

Change the url for different Versions

Answer (score 2):

Just take this [bookmarklet](https://gist.github.com/1514269) and you should be able to jQuerify any page ^_^

[Here it is](https://gist.github.com/1514277) **not** minified.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can do it from the console:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "....";    // URL to jQuery 
document.head.appendChild(s);
```